# Symfony 4.4.* hslavich/oneloginsaml-bundle - how to load certificates from file path?

Tags: php, symfony, certificate, saml, onelogin

According to README.md from https://github.com/hslavich/OneloginSamlBundle/tree/1.x

The only way to provide certificate for OneloginSaml is via app/config/config.yml
We strongly don't want to load them by pasting it into yaml file, instead, we want to load certificates from a file, given the path to the file in this yaml file.

I noticed that the only way to achieve this would be to override the class HslavichOneloginSamlExtension.

What is the "right" way to override a HslavichOneloginSamlExtension class to allow certificates to be loaded from a file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The would suggest using environment variables for private certificates and use them in .yml files likes this:

```
privateKey: '%env(PRIVATE_KEY)%'
```

I think it is not possible to load a file in a yml config.

Comment: We have managed to solve this by using "symplify/config-transformer" to generate .yml files via PHP code, this is temporary solution.

Comment: In Symfony 5.3+ you can use Config Builder Classes.